# Child user control doesn't fire its registered event

Tags: asp.net, events, user-controls, updatepanel, repeater

So here's my layout of controls, I've removed the formatting of tables and what not. The issue that I'm having is that the event `InterventionSaved` is always null.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAreaConcern_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updIntervenion" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                 <UC:InterventionLayout ID="InterventionLayout" runat="server"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the page code behind I'm trying to register the event `InterventionLayout.InterventionSaved` for each item in the `repeater1`.

```
   protected void rptAreaConcern_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
            {
                        InterventionLayout InterventionLayout = ((InterventionLayout)e.Item.FindControl("InterventionLayout"));
                        //InterventionLayout.ProgressMonitor = ddlProgressMonitoringOwner;  //tried to pass the drop 
                        //InterventionLayout.ProgressMonitorDuration = ddlDuration;   //down lists to the control(fail)
                        InterventionLayout.InterventionSaved += new EventHandler(NonAcademicInterventionSaved);
                        InterventionLayout.LoadAssignedInterventionData();
    }


   private void NonAcademicInterventionSaved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //this never gets called
       //ParentSave();
       //UpdatePanel();
    }
```

Now in my usercontrol `InterventionLayout.ascx.cs` I have a save button that calls `Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I have the even defined as:

```
public event EventHandler InterventionSaved;

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Save();
            if(null != InterventionSaved) // this is always null
               InterventionSaved(this, new EventArgs()); 
        }
```

InterventionSaved is always null.  I don't know why or if I am doing something wrong. I know it set in the control when I step into `InterventionLayout.LoadAssignedInterventionData()`.  Then when I have my break point set in `btnSave_Click` `InterventionSaved` is always null.

My main goal it to be able to notify the parent and run its `NonAcademicInterventionSaved()` method. From there I would like to eventually cause the updatepanel to refresh.  What I'm trying to do shouldn't be complicated but its turning out to be more of a headache than expected.

Comment: I am not 100% shure if the issue is the controll inside the repeater or the UpdatePanel. If you remove the UpdatePanel is  NonAcademicInterventionSaved fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :
[button event in nested repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345146/button-event-in-nested-repeater)

**Ensure that its being added in the onItemCreated**

@user655810: but this is exactly your case. A Usercontrol in a nested repeater and believe me, it works ;) Where did you add the handler? You must add it in ItemCreated of the nested repeater like in my example and not in ItemDataBound(ItemCreated is called on every postback as against ItemDataBound). – Tim Schmelter Mar 18 at 16:23

Answer (score 0):

You may have to rebuild the repeater-collection of InterventionLayouts upon post-back so ASP.NET can match up the events.